# How to dynamically push an array using spread operator Javascript

Tags: javascript, ngrx

```
[
  {
    "details": {
      "name": "john",
      "point": "20"
    },

    "list": {
      "number": "30",

    }
  },
  {
    "details": {
      "name": "doe",
      "point": "25"
    },
    "list": {
      "number": "30",

    }
  }
]
```

This is what i am trying to do, i am getting the data from the store and if the response is only one i use data = getData[0].details and if the response is more than one then i push the data using [...data, ...getData[1].details] if there are more than one data how can i achieve. thanks in advance

```
 let data:any = [];
     this.store
              .pipe(
                select(getData),
                map((getData,i) => {
                  if (getData) {
                      data = [...data, ...getData[i].details]
                  }
             return data;
                })
             )
```

Comment: I'm very confused what are trying to do here, can you elaborate a bit more in your question? Please include an example of what the desired output would be. Also, I don't understand how `select(getData)` can work, isn't `getData` defined only inside `map`'s callback?

Comment: I assume getData is the result of some API callback

Comment: But then it wouldn't exist in `select(getData)`

Comment: Yes select(getdata) is the response from api

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get an array of the details. 
In this case you can say.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "details": {
      "name": "john",
      "point": "20"
    },

    "list": {
      "number": "30",

    }
  },
  {
    "details": {
      "name": "doe",
      "point": "25"
    },
    "list": {
      "number": "30",

    }
  }
];

let details = data.map(a => a.details);

console.log(details);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i understand what you mean:

What I would do is map over your `getData` response and add to the original array on each iteration. It wont matter if there is 1 or many in the getData array:

```
getData.map(x => $data.push(x.details));
```